# Get Values from dynamic textbox?

Tags: php, jquery

I have this codes that create a textbox, and each textbox has it's own unique id eg textbox1, textbox2 so on. I had trouble in submitting the data because the textbox is dynamic, u will not know how many textbox created by the user., so I dont have idea on how to post the data eg., $_POST['textbox'],.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 2;

    $("#addButton").click(function () {

    if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
    }   

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<input type="text" name="txtLine' + counter + '" id="txtLine' + counter + '" placeholder="Line#' + counter +' " >');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


    counter++;
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can submit the form elements with square brackets like so and it will post all of the form inputs as an array:

```
<form method="post" action="form.php">
  <input name="txtLine[]" />
  <input name="txtLine[]" />
  <input name="txtLine[]" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You can then access all of them in an array like so `$_POST["txtLine"]`

Output of `$_POST`:

```
Array
(
    [txtLine] => Array
        (
            [0] => hey
            [1] => there
            [2] => jack
        )

)
```

Comment: so u mean,instead of using counter to create unique ID,.i should use []?

Comment: You can still use the counter to create a unique ID for the HTML id or class name, but for the name you can use the square brackets and that will be accessible as an array on the PHP side.

Comment: Thanks,. In the file where in it post the data.. I added these codes
$text = $_POST['text'];
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 echo count($text);
 foreach ($text as $txt)
 {
  echo $txt. ' ';
 }
 


}
HOPE IT HELPS ... thx